# Proper return value for __len__ for an object that acts as an infinite sequence

Tags: python, infinite, python-datamodel

I am writing a python class that acts as an immutable, infinite sequence.

The class does not use a generator to access this infinite sequence, rather it generates a value for an arbitrary index in the sequence according to an algorithm within the `__getitem__` method.

I am curious what the best way to handle the `__len__` method of such an object is. Ideally, I would just return `float("inf")` through `__len__`. However, the `len()` function that calls an object's `__len__` method behind the scenes requires a somewhat specific value.

If `__len__` is set to return float("inf") or decimal.Decimal("Infinity"), `len()` rejects it by raising a TypeError. It also rejects the value of "-1" which would imply that the sequence is infinite. Furthermore, when I tried using an infinity class that I happen to have written earlier that *does* in fact inherit from `int`, `len()` for whatever reason returned 0.

While it isn't really a major inconvenience to allow the value to just be "0", and while a class like this is very unusual, I am still curious to know, is there a good way to handle the length attribute of a class that is an infinite sequence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__len__()` must return a valid integer.  Since you cannot, you should either not implement `__len__()`, if your sequences are always infinite, or raise a `ValueError` if you can sometimes give a meaningful length.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only reasonable solution is to not implement `__len__` at all, since in fact your object does not have a length.

Answer (score 3):

Don't define `__len__` for this class because that's semantically impossible to answer for it.

Answer (score 3):

As noted and in the documentation [`__len__` must return an integer >= 0](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), hence the `TypeError`.

Follow the example set by the infinite [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and raise an appropriate `TypeError` to signify no length:

```
from itertools import cycle
c = cycle("a")
len(c)

TypeError: object of type 'itertools.cycle' has no len()
```

Comment: `itertools.cycle` doesn't itself raise the `TypeError`. It simply doesn't define `__len__`, and `len` raises the `TypeError` for it. You'd see essentially the same error if you did, say, `len(3)`.